# JSON: String To Array

Tags: jquery

Im working with the datatables plugin with JQUERY and I have to get my string into an array. The below code works when I manually set the array.

```
var myarray = [['Joe','Smith',20,3], ['Kayla','Smith',32,1]]
dt.clear().rows.add(myArray).draw();
```

when I run console.log(myarray)

```
[Array[4], Array[4]]
```

now when I have a string that I get from the back end its in the exact same format, however, like i said its a string.

I tried something like this on a string thats in this format: [['Joe','Smith',20,3], ['Kayla','Smith',32,1]]

```
var myArray = new Array(mystring);
```

but when I run console.log(myArray) I get

```
["[['Joe','Smith',20,3], ['PG','Kayla','Smith',32,1]]"]
```

Not sure how to get it in the right format.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply turn a string representation of an array into an array by passing it to the `Array` constructor. You will need to use valid JSON syntax (i.e. replacing single `'` quotes with `"` double ones).

You can then use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the string back into an array as follows:

```js
let myArray = JSON.parse('[["Joe","Smith",20,3],["Kayla","Smith",32,1]]');
console.log(myArray);
```